# How can I activate Plasma Application Launcher accelerator keys?

Tags: launcher, plasma, keyboard-accelerators

All applications in Kubuntu have accelerator keys - except the application launcher.  I'd like to be able to open the application launcher and type my way through sub-menus (each activated with one keystroke) to the application I want and launch it with one keystroke. Is there some way to activate accelerator keys for application launcher?  Or, do I need to put in a request for a new feature?  Where can I do that?

Comment: If you know the name of your application, say ksudoku, just press the super key (the Win key) and start typing k,s,u, (without the commas) by which time you'll see ksudoku suggested to you. Highlight it with the up or down arrow key and press enter. This approach will work even for files. You can float your ideas at https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-users/ for starters or at https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/kubuntu-devel. All the best!

Comment: Thanks for responding @DKBose.  I guess that I'll have to accept that Plasma does not have what I was used to in Win7.  I know how to use it as you've said - typing in the name or part of the name of the program I want.  I have also taken to making Meta+[character] short cuts to launch some of my oft-used applications.  Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: My comment, sadly, doesn't address your issue which is the lack of accelerator keys to traverse menus and submenus. By the way, there's a nice, relatively recent, article titled "KDE and the Menu Crisis" @  http://www.ocsmag.com/2017/08/25/kde-and-the-menu-crisis/